# How to well adjust a loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am currently writing a little program to ask a PinCode to a user and return ":)" if the Pin is good or ":(" if the Pin is wrong.
My code is made of one java file and one text file.

This is the code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static public boolean readPinsData(File dataFile, ArrayList<Integer> data) {
   boolean err = false;
   try {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
      String line;
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
         line = scanner.nextLine();
         try {
            data.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = true;
         }
      }
      scanner.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      err = true;
   }

   return err;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println("MY APP");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    Console console = System.console();
    int pinSize = 0;
    int nbTry = 0;

    do{
      do{
    char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter pin: ");
    pinSize = passwordArray.length;

    if(pinSize != 4){
            System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Checking...");
        }


   ArrayList<Integer> pins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   readPinsData(new File("bdd.txt"), pins);
   //System.out.println(pins);
   //System.out.println(passwordArray);


   String[] thePins = new String[pins.size()];
   for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
    thePins[i] = pins.get(i).toString();
}

   String passEntered = String.valueOf(passwordArray);





   for(int i = 0 ; i < thePins.length ; i++){
      if(passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4){
          System.out.println(":)");
        } else if(!passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4){
            nbTry++;
        }

    }   

  }while(nbTry < 3);
   }while(pinSize != 4);

}
}
```

This is bdd.txt where all the good Pins are stored :

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
6666
7777
8888
9999
```

Actually my problem is to limit the number of try to 3 tries. I need to explain:

--> the user has to enter a pin

--> either he enters a good 4 digits pin and it prints ":)" (and the app is done)

--> either he enters a wrong 4 digits pin and it prints ":(" and the nbTry must be ++.
In this case he has only 2 tries left

--> he also can enter a 1-digit pin or 2-digits pin or 3-digits pin ... and in this case nbTry is not affected, he just have to re-enter a 4 digits pin.

I can not find out how to do with the nbTry left part.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want him to be able to enter a 4 digit pin only or do you want him to be able to enter any length of pin?

Edit:

Reading your `main` I saw that you have two 'do...while`. If you change the order of them It should work. I can't test it atm because I'm on mobile bit try it like this:

```
do {
  do {
      ....
  } while (pinSize != 4);
} while (nbTry < 3);
```

Edit2:

```
boolean loginCorrdect = false;
for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
   if (passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4) {
      System.out.println(":)");
      booleanCorrect = true;
      break;
   } else if (!passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4) {
      System.out.println(":(");
   }

}
if(!booleanCorrect && pinSize == 4){
   nbTry++;
}
```

Hope you got it as its hard to type on mobile.

The full main code:
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
System.out.println("-----------------------");
System.out.println("MY APP");
System.out.println("-----------------------");
Console console = System.console();
int pinSize = 0;
int nbTry = 0;
boolean authenticated = false;

do {
   do {
      char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter pin: ");
      pinSize = passwordArray.length();

      if (pinSize != 4) {
     System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
      } else {
     System.out.println("Checking...");
      }

      ArrayList<Integer> pins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      readPinsData(new File("bdd.txt"), pins);
      // System.out.println(pins);
      // System.out.println(passwordArray);

      String[] thePins = new String[pins.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
         thePins[i] = pins.get(i).toString();
      }

      String passEntered = String.valueOf(passwordArray);

      for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
         if (passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4) {
    System.out.println(":)");
    authenticated = true;
    break;
}
}

} while (pinSize != 4);
  if (!authenticated && pinSize == 4) {
System.out.println(":(");
nbTry++;
 }
} while (nbTry < 3 && !authenticated);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please add a comment to the question.

Comment: Any length of pin. If he enters a pin with a lenth < or > to 4 digits, it will just print "Pin must be 4 digits" but the number of try will not be affected. The number of try is only affected when a wrong 4-digits pin is entered

Comment: I'm sorry...I'm not allowd to do that atm so I need to ask it as comment and then edit my question to fit the purpose.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work.. After only one wrong pin, the app stops. I can not ask him to try 2 more times

Comment: Okay I got the problem...In your loop you raise the amount of tries. You need to do that outside the loop like in my solution in the post.

Comment: Thank you LostKatana, I tried your solution and it worked perfectly, I have nothing else to add. Thanks again !

Comment: One more thing. I recently was adviced to rather code to interfaces than implementations so you should change `ArrayList<Integer> pins = new ArrayList<Integer>();` to `List<Integer> pins = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can do it like so (and you should close() your Scanner when done) -

```
static public boolean readPinsData(File dataFile, ArrayList<Integer> data) {
    boolean err = false;
    Scanner scanner = null; // so we can close the Scanner.
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                data.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                err = true;
            }
            // Limit it to 3 attempts. Set err on 3rd.
            if (data.size() >= 3) {
                err = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        err = true;
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) { // Close the Scanner.
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I have tried your solution, but this way 4444 or 5555 or no longer good Pins... Maybe I have explained it wrong. The number of tries has to be ++ only in the case where the user enter a wrong 4-digits pin. (We can assimilate to a credit card Pin, we have a 4-digits code, if we enter 3 wrong pin it's done)

Comment: @FlorentP No. In this way, you can only enter 3 pins. After 3 pins added to the list it will set the error flag and end the loop.

Comment: I do not understand, I try some good pins and it did not match with my bdd.txt file. What does it change exactly?

Answer (score 1):

What helps is to have a top-down refinement of your control flow / logic.
As this reeks a bit of home work, just an idea:

```
Set<String> pins = readPINs();
boolean authenticated = false;
for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; ++attempt) {
    String pin = askForPIN();
    if (!isSyntacticalValidPIN(pin)) {
       giveError();
       break;
    } else if (pins.contains{pin)) {
       authenticated = true;
       break;
    }
}
if (authenticated) {
    offerMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joop, actually I do not need to simulate a menu, my program is just based on Pin authentication. If good --> :) If wrong --> :( Just it, so that is why I need to limit the number of wrong Pin to 3.

Comment: why break on `!isSyntacticalValidPIN`?

Comment: Yes I did not exactly write down the correct logic; just gave an example how to start a formulation of an algorithm.